# Created schema with DataGrip how to backup and migrate

Tags: datagrip

I have just implemented my DB Schema with Jetbrains new DataGrip IDE. The schema now exists on my DB server instance that is running locally.

In other IDE's I can save the work as a "Project" or save the SQL to a file. I don't see any option in DataGrip, except for `Copy DDL`, which I have tried and it copies my schema along with a lot of other stuff.

Is that the only option or am I supposed to do it through a PostgreSQL management tool. I want to save my work.

Thanks. Also, please don't just mark this to be closed. I have seen many other questions like this on StackOverflow. i.e. Asking how to perform some action on a tool related to software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in "default" project by default. Go to File/Project and create your own which can be opened later by File/Open recent, for example.